# Is there a way to retrieve the pixel width of the browser window with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to move objects on my web page with javascript depending on the screen size. Is there a way to retrieve the pixel width of the browser window?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`alert(`[`$(window).width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width) `)`;

Comment: using jQuery to access `window.innerWidth` seems excessive.

Comment: Yeah, but he tagged it with jQuery. If it's already loaded i guess it's fine... i submitted a purely JS version to get the "real" innerwidth tho.

Comment: @zzzzBov - jQuery may be inefficent, but `window.innerWidth` is not cross-browser.

Comment: @zzzz Yes; both the title and tags imply that he's looking for the jQuery answer to me.

Comment: @galambalazs which browser, and what's the fix? @Matt I upvoted your answer for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
function getWindowWidth() {
        var windowWidth = 0;
        if (typeof(window.innerWidth) == 'number') {
            windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
        }
        else {
            if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientWidth) {
                windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
            }
            else {
                if (document.body && document.body.clientWidth) {
                    windowWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
                }
            }
        }
        return windowWidth;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course getting the window size may be necessary to do what you want, but in many cases it's better to deal with the issues of different window sizes using simple CSS. You do know that you can place an object relative to the right edge using the CSS property `right`?

Another useful trick is to use margin to make a div fill all but x pixels, that way you can make a number of elements take up a specific amount of space each and make the last one take the rest.

Comment: yeah, i understand what your saying, but I am trying to make it so that everything looks good from screen sizes of 10" to 27" without making the page fixed width. What do you think?

Comment: You probably need some hard-coding for doing that, but you could probably make good use of some of the lighter tools in the toolbox. While such things always depend on the job, based on your limited description I would suggest making a few different layouts using the CSS methods, and then choose between them depending on screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Don't. Use jQuery UI draggable.

Comment: I don't think the OP wants _users_ to be able to move objects.

Comment: yeah, no I don't want draggableness.